# My flutter app build process fails after the first run and debug

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble adding assets to my Flutter app. If I add my assets folder (myAssets) like below in pubspec.yaml everything is fine on the first run and debug.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - myAssets/
```

On the second run and debug, it will give me a build process failed exception.

When I run the app from Windows command prompt I get the error:

> 'flutterProjects\meanartist2\meanartist\myAssets\cyborgrobot.jpeg'
> (OS Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Am I missing something fundamental? Should I delete the build folder manually after every run, or am I missing code to clean up at the program end? I'm fairly new to Flutter, as you may have guessed :)

Deleting the build folder after every run fixes the issue, but I don't understand why or if this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any problems with your pubspec.yaml file and it's not normal for a Flutter project to require the build folder to be deleted after every run.

The only thing that I am finding strange is that you are using a backslash instead of a forward slash for your image path.

Comment: In my main.dart file I'm using the forward slash. As in AssetImage('myAssets/firetornado.jpeg'). The backslash is how the paths are outputted when I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with the same issue I managed to resolve this by reinstalling vs code and deleting the flutter sdk. I also went all out and removed all trace of the flutter and dart extensions form vscode. Everything is now working normally.